# inner JOIN mysql query issue

Tags: mysql

Have 2 tables TABLE1 and TABLE2

Have to fetch record from both table in below given 2 criteria with INNER JOIN.

```
[1] Fetch record from when TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id
[2] Fetch record from when TABLE1.id NOT IN TABLE2.id field
```

CAN any one tell query for both criteria.

*Edit:*

**table1**

```
id
1
2
3
```

**table2**

```
id
1
2
```

**result for criteria 1**

***1, 2***

**result for criteria 2**

***3***

Comment: No I am facing this issue in my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
SELECT * FROM [Table1] 
INNER JOIN [Table2] On [Table1].[ID]=[Table2].[ID]
```

2)

```
SELECT * FROM [table1] 
LEFT JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].[ID]=[Table2].[ID]
WHERE [Table2].[ID] IS NULL
```

EDIT: Tested option 2 and it works as expected

Comment: No it is not working ...see my post update to get better understanding of my post

Comment: Do you mean they are one query and not two?

Comment: Please have a look at my post again ...i have added example

Comment: Im getting the output you provided. Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: I am getting 0 records in 2 criteria

Comment: Hi Poonam, are you using '= NULL' at the end of the query or 'IS NULL'?

Comment: Here is another example on another site, its the same as mine so should work! http://data.agaric.com/node/2245

Comment: I was using = NULL ...my mistake ...gr8 IS NULL worked ...thanks